# Visual Studio 2015 failed to deploy application in device?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

> DEP6200 : Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. 0x89731810:
>   Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a
>   phone is connected and powered on.    myapplication.WindowsPhone

I have registered the device(Lumia 540 DUAL SIM) successfully with the Windows phone 8.1 device registration tool before 2 months. The application has been deployed and debugged perfectly till 2 months. But suddenly, Visual studio 2015 has started to give me the error while debugging/running the application in the device.

I have restarted the device, my PC. I have restarted the IpOverUsbSvc service. I have tried to register this device again. But I am getting the following error while using windows phone 8.1 device registration tool.

> Unable to connect to a phone. Make sure that the Windows phone IP Over
>   USB transport(IpOverUsbSvc) service is running.

Comment: What OS do you have on the desktop? Is the Phone Companion app running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rowland Shaw for your efforts to the help.

It is resolved by uninstalling all the driver related to the Lumia 540.  Restart the phone.
Restart the PC.

When I faced this error, I had uninstalled the Lumia 540 driver but forgot to remove other three usb driver related to the phone.